# How to create a second dropdown menu to reduce single dropdown menu list size

Tags: php

I have a dropdown menu of about 40 city names where the user can choose the city he wants the weather forecast to be displayed. I need to add more cities to this list but I am afraid it will become too large to be "pratical".

My idea is to organize cities by countries and create a new drop down menu to choose country first and then choose city.

I have been trying several solutions I found in similar requests, but since I am a begginer, my problem is that I always get errors when I try to include country names in the the array and then make changes in the script to make it work.

Current script is something like:

```
<?php
    $arr = ["city_code1" => "city_name1", 
            "city_code2" => "city_name2", 
            ---
            "city_codei" => "city_namei"] 

    $city = isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : array_keys($arr)[0];
?>

<form name="f" id="a" method="post" action="">
    <select id="city" name="city" onchange="this.form.submit()" >                      
    <?php
        foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
            echo "<option value='$k'" . ($k == $city ? " selected" : "") . ">$v</option>\n";
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</form>

<?php
    //create url
    $city_name = $arr[$city];
    $fIOURL = "http://www.exemple.com/{$city_name}";

    // check cache
    $city_cache = "cache/{$city_name}.txt";
    $cache_exists = file_exists($city_cache);
    if (!$cache_exists || time() - filemtime($city_cache) > 60 * 60 * 3) { 
        // cache doesn't exist, or is no longer valid
        $rawData = file_get_contents($fIOURL);
        if ($rawData != "") {
            // if we successfully fetched data, recreate the cache
            $cache_exists = file_put_contents($city_cache, $rawData);
        }
    }

    if ($cache_exists) {
        // fetch the data (either cached or freshly loaded) from the cache file
        $rawData = file_get_contents($city_cache);
        $forecastLoadedTime = filemtime($city_cache);
    }
    else {
        // some sort of error message here
        $rawData = "Error no forecast available for $city_name!";
    }

    $decoded = json_decode($rawData, true);
```

How can I add a country dropdown menu and change code to reflect that?
Thank you so much in advance for some help!

Answer (score 0):

**Option1:**
Easy way to handle this in `onchange` event in jquery for country & state select inputs & apply your logic. I have fiddled here for getting states dynamically on selecting a country, you might be able to code the rest yourself - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YqLh8/)

**Option2:** Implementation of ajax feature while selecting country. On changing the country you can send a request through ajax to fetch city detail from another php file then update the second dropdown. Here is example [example1](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/populate-state-dropdown-based-on-selection-in-country-dropdown-using-jquery.php) and [example2](https://phppot.com/php/country-state-city-example-cascading-jquery-dependent-dropdown/)

Comment: Thank you so much Rasa Mohamed for your precious help. I am going to try both options and I will let you know which one of them worked better for my case.

Comment: @MeteoCaldas No Issues, try and update if you have any queries!

Comment: I have used your precious help for creating the menus but eas not able to achieve a solution for what I intend to do. I am asking for mor help and everything is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57873009/  Can you please take a look? Thank you so much.