# How to create a dropdown submenu and associate it to the array that was used by the previous single menu?

Tags: php

I have a single dropdown menu list with 20 cities, so the user can select one specific city and get its weather forecast. It is working fine as you can check here https://meteolitoral.com/previsao5.php

The problem is that now I want to add more 80 cities to the previous list, but that would make an "endless" and "unpratical" dropdown menu of 100 cities!

My idea to solve this problem is to organize cities by "states", so that each state will only have a small number of cities to choose from.

This is achieved by a dropdown menu of states and a submenu of cities for the selected state.

I have already done it, but to make things much easier, I want to keep using the same array of cities and city_codes that I was using on the single drop down menu. The problem is that I can't find a way to associate this array to the new dropdown cities submenu.

You can see what I have already done here : https://www.meteolitoral.com/previsaon.php

The new states menu and cities submenu:

```
    <form id="dropdowns" action="">

    <!--    <label>States:</label>-->
            <select id="states" name="states">
                <option value="000">- Select State -</option>
            </select>

        <br />

    <!--    <label>Cities:</label> -->
            <select id="cities" name="network">
                <option value="000">- Select City -</option>
            </select>


    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myJson = {
"states": [
    {
        "name": "State 1",
        "id": "state1",
        "cities": [
            {
                "name": "City A",
                "id": "31880",
            },
            {
                "name": "City B",
                "id": "31994",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "State 2",
        "id": "state2",
        "cities": [
            {
                "name": "City C",
                "id": "31937",
            },
            {
                "name": "City D",
                "id": "32046",
            }
        ]
       }
    ]
 }


$.each(myJson.states, function (index, value) {
$("#states").append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
});

$('#states').on('change', function(){
console.log($(this).val());
for(var i = 0; i < myJson.states.length; i++)
{
  if(myJson.states[i].id == $(this).val())
  {
     $('#cities').html('<option value="000">- Select City -</option>');
     $.each(myJson.states[i].cities, function (index, value) {
        $("#cities").append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
    });
  }
}
});
</script>
```

Former single drop down menu that uses the array that needs to be associated with the new cities submenu:

```
 <?php
 $arr = ["31880" => "City A", 
        "31994" => "City B", 
        "31937" => "City C", 
        "32046" => "City D"] 

$city = isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : array_keys($arr)[0];
?>

<form name="f" id="a" method="post" action="">
<select id="city" name="city" onchange="this.form.submit()" >                      
<?php
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        echo "<option value='$k'" . ($k == $city ? " selected" : "") . ">$v</option>\n";
    }
?>
</select>
</form>
```

So, what I am trying to do and not achieving is:

1. After selecting one state in the main dropdown menu
2. After selecting one city of that state in the cities dropdown menu
3. make the needed changes in current code so that any chosen city can use the current array ($arr) and keeping the rest of the code unchanged since it works perfectly.

I have to admit that I am a beginner and sometimes that makes small details become huge problems :-)

Thank you so much in advance for your precious help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved thanks to @kaczmen

"You are submiting a form with default GET method but actually looking for a POST parameter here: $city = isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : array_keys($arr)[0];.

Change it to $city = isset($_GET['city']) ? $_GET['city'] : array_keys($arr)[0]; or change your form tag to form id="dropdowns" method="POST" and it should be working as expected."

I also had to remove this part:

```
<form name="f" id="a" method="post" action="">
<select id="city" name="city" onchange="this.form.submit()" >                      
<?php
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
echo "<option value='$k'" . ($k == $city ? " selected" : "") . ">$v</option>\n";
}
?>
</select>
</form>
```